# Converting images in a folder to grayscale using python and opencv and writing it to a specific folder

Tags: python, opencv, grayscale

```
import glob
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
images=[]
images=np.array(images)
path='C:\Users\Quantum\Desktop\test'
count=0
images = [cv2.imread(file,0) for file in glob.glob("E:\homework\Computer vision\Faces\*.jpg")]
for i in range(len(images)):
#    im = Image.fromarray(images[i])
#    cv2.imwrite(str(path) + '.jpg', images[count])
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'pic.jpg'), images[count])
    count+=1
```

Trying to select all the images from a folder and the images are getting selected and are converted to grayscale although I dont know how to write those images to a specific folder.Kindly help

Comment: You can do it very simply at the commandline with **ImageMagick** by the way. Convert all JPEGs in current directory to greyscale and write to directory called `greyscale`... `mkdir greyscale; mogrify -path greyscale -colorspace gray *.jpg`

Answer (score 8):

**#multiple image conversions**

```
import cv2

import os,glob

from os import listdir,makedirs

from os.path import isfile,join
path = '/root/Desktop/Anil' # Source Folder
dstpath = '/root/Desktop/Anil2' # Destination Folder
try:
    makedirs(dstpath)
except:
    print ("Directory already exist, images will be written in same folder")
# Folder won't used
files = list(filter(lambda f: isfile(join(path,f)), listdir(path)))
for image in files:
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,image))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        dstPath = join(dstpath,image)
        cv2.imwrite(dstPath,gray)
    except:
        print ("{} is not converted".format(image))
for fil in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(fil) 
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(os.path.join(path,image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to greyscale
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dstpath,fil),gray_image)
    except:
        print('{} is not converted')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import cv2
import glob, os, errno

# Replace mydir with the directory you want
mydir = r'C:\Users\Quantum\Desktop\testoutput'

#check if directory exist, if not create it
try:
    os.makedirs(mydir)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
        raise
for fil in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    image = cv2.imread(fil) 
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to greyscale
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(mydir,fil),gray_image) # write to location with same name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os,cv2
path = r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\folder' # Source Folder
dstpath = r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\desfolder' # Destination Folder



try:
    makedirs(dstpath)
except:
    print ("Directory already exist, images will be written in asme folder")

# Folder won't used
files = os.listdir(path)

for image in files:
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,image))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dstpath,image),gray)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
from os import listdir,makedirs
from os.path import isfile,join

path = r'C:\Users\fakabbir.amin\Desktop\pdfop' # Source Folder
dstpath = r'C:\Users\fakabbir.amin\Desktop\testfolder' # Destination Folder

try:
    makedirs(dstpath)
except:
    print ("Directory already exist, images will be written in asme folder")

# Folder won't used
files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,f))] 

for image in files:
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,image))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        dstPath = join(dstpath,image)
        cv2.imwrite(dstPath,gray)
    except:
        print ("{} is not converted".format(image))
```

This code snippet will take all the images from **path** and write into another folder mentioned in **dstpath**.