# how to change input_shape to one channel like (64,64,1) from my code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

so I have a dataset in the form of a grayscale image, that means one channel right?

I changed input_shape to 64.64.1 from this code

```
classifier.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(2,2), input_shape = (64, 64, 1)))
```

but i got error

```
Error when checking input: expected zero_padding2d_1_input to have shape (64, 64, 1) but got array with shape (64, 64, 3)
```

what's wrong with that and how can I run training with one channel input_shape (64,64,1)?

full code can you see on this [Why my acc always higher but my val_acc is very small?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57635645/why-my-acc-always-higher-but-my-val-acc-is-very-small)

Comment: in the first layer in your original code, you are having input_shape as (64,64,3) . If you want to train it as (64,64,1) convert your image to gray scale and it becomes (64,64) then expand dims at -1 , so it becomes (64,64,1)

Comment: thx for reply, can you provide the code to change all the images in the folder to grayscale? I have searched but can its convert one image only. I really need this

Comment: you can try imagemagick - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262968/convert-entire-folder-to-greyscale-using-image-magick

Comment: i try this code (end page) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087528/converting-images-in-a-folder-to-grayscale-using-python-and-opencv-and-writing-i/51834486.  its can converting all my images to grayscale. but when I tried to run my cnn model again, it still give the error ValueError: Error when checking input: expected zero_padding2d_1_input to have shape (64, 64, 1) but got array with shape (64, 64, 3)

Comment: did u change your first layer of model with input_shape= (64,64,1) ?

Comment: yes, i change it from (64,64,3) to (64,64,1)

Comment: in your flow_from_directory set color_mode = "grayscale"

Comment: wow its running bro, after i add color_mode = "grayscale"  thank you very much

Comment: i will type this down as an answer, so that you can mark it as accepted and will help future users.

Comment: and now, do I still need to change input_shape to (64,64,1) or still use (64,64,3) after adding color mode ? is there any effect for result?

Comment: shape must be 64,64,1

Comment: great, big thanks bro :)

Comment: please verify the answer below, and mark it as accepted if you find the answer useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason is all your images are RGB and are read as RGB images by keras flow from directory by default. So set the flow_from_directory to read your images as grayscale and set the input_shape in the first layer to (64,64,1)

code sample for flow_from_directory

```
 train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary',
                                                 color_mode = "grayscale")
```

)